I cannot make code to record from a USB microphone; only the internal laptop microphone is being recorded
I have written the following script in Java, which is meant to record a few seconds of audio from a microphone.
The problem is that it only wants to record the internal laptop microphone, instead of the external USB microphone.
The USB microphone is correctly recorded using an analogous Python script, which means that it can be detected and it is fully working.
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class SimpleAudioRecorder {

    private static final float SAMPLE_RATE = 44100; // Audio sample rate
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096; // Buffer size for audio recording
    private static final float GAIN_FACTOR = 1.0f; // Amplification factor for microphone input (adjusted)
    private static final File OUTPUT_FILE = new File("recording.wav"); // Output file path
    private static final int RECORD_DURATION_MS = 5000; // Record duration in milliseconds (5 seconds)

    private static TargetDataLine microphone;
    private static volatile boolean recordingStopped = false; // Flag to indicate if recording is stopped

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Initialize audio components
            AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE, 16, 2, true, true);
            initializeMicrophone(format);
            startRecording();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void initializeMicrophone(AudioFormat format) {
        try {
            // Get and open the microphone
            DataLine.Info micInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
            if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(micInfo)) {
                System.err.println("Microphone not supported");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            microphone = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(micInfo);
            microphone.open(format);
            System.out.println("Microphone initialized and opened.");
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private static void startRecording() {
        System.out.println("Recording started!");
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // Set up a timer to stop recording after 5 seconds
        Timer stopTimer = new Timer();
        stopTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                stopRecording(); // Stop the recording after 5 seconds
                saveRecording(outputStream); // Save the recording
            }
        }, RECORD_DURATION_MS);

        microphone.start();
        System.out.println("Microphone started.");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead;

        // Record audio
        while (!recordingStopped) {
            bytesRead = microphone.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            if (bytesRead > 0) {
                // Amplify the audio data correctly by scaling up each sample
                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead - 1; i += 2) {
                    // Convert byte pair (little-endian) into a 16-bit signed sample
                    short sample = (short) ((buffer[i + 1] << 8) | (buffer[i] & 0xff));

                    // Apply gain factor to amplify the sample
                    sample = (short) Math.min(Math.max(sample * GAIN_FACTOR, Short.MIN_VALUE), Short.MAX_VALUE);

                    // Break the 16-bit sample back into two bytes (little-endian)
                    buffer[i] = (byte) sample;
                    buffer[i + 1] = (byte) (sample >> 8);
                }
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }

        // Stop and close the microphone
        microphone.stop();
        microphone.close();
        System.out.println("Microphone stopped and closed.");
    }

    private static void saveRecording(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream) {
        try {
            // Save the recorded audio to a file
            byte[] audioData = outputStream.toByteArray();
            saveAudioToFile(audioData, new AudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE, 16, 2, true, true));
            System.out.println("Recording saved to " + OUTPUT_FILE.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void saveAudioToFile(byte[] audioData, AudioFormat format) throws IOException {
        byte[] normalizedAudioData = normalizeVolume(audioData);

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE);
             BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos)) {

            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(normalizedAudioData), format, normalizedAudioData.length / format.getFrameSize());

            AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, bos);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] normalizeVolume(byte[] audioData) {
        short[] audioDataShort = new short[audioData.length / 2];
        ByteBuffer.wrap(audioData).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(audioDataShort);

        // Find the maximum absolute value
        int max = 0; // Change type to int
        for (short sample : audioDataShort) {
            int absSample = Math.abs(sample); // Convert to int for abs calculation
            if (absSample > max) {
                max = absSample;
            }
        }

        // Calculate normalization factor
        float normalizationFactor = 32767.0f / max;

        // Apply normalization
        for (int i = 0; i < audioDataShort.length; i++) {
            audioDataShort[i] = (short) Math.min(Math.max(audioDataShort[i] * normalizationFactor, Short.MIN_VALUE), Short.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(audioDataShort.length * 2).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        ShortBuffer shortBuffer = byteBuffer.asShortBuffer();
        shortBuffer.put(audioDataShort);
        return byteBuffer.array();
    }

    private static void stopRecording() {
        System.out.println("Stopping recording...");
        recordingStopped = true; // Set flag to true to stop recording
    }
}

